# Can an off-chain worker read/write the state of an EVM contract?

Tags: frontier, evm, offchain-worker

Let's assume we have a frontier-based node with smart contract `X`. From an off-chain worker, we want to call `X.some_method()` which will return data, and then the worker would use this data to make some business decisions and submit a transaction back to update the contract state. Would that be possible by directly calling the evm pallet from the off-chain worker, without the need to make RPC calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about EVM and Frontier, but in general offchain workers cannot write to the state directly, so if they call into a function directly that has some side effect, it will be ignored. The **only** way for them to write to state is to emit a transaction back to the local node and the rest of the network.

Thus,

> Would that be possible by directly calling the evm pallet from the off-chain worker, without the need to make RPC calls?

I believe no.

Comment: OK, but couldn't such transaction be emitted by a mere function call in Rust, instead of making an HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, there are helper functions made for offchain workers to send both signed and unsigned transactions: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/offchain/index.html